# Install Docker on Agent in Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to install Docker on the build agent or set it as a requirement?

My tests try to run Docker on the command line but this doesn't seem to work.

I would have expected to add it as a `Demand` but adding `docker` doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the hosted agent, no. You can't install additional software on the hosted agent.

The software available on the hosted agent is [well-documented](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software).

If you need software installed beyond those that can't be installed as a local package, you'll need to set up your own private agent and configure it appropriately.

Comment: From what I can see the Hosted Linux Agent (Preview) should have Docker installed (your link points to this `Dockerfile` for the Hosted Linux Agent Preview: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/blob/master/ubuntu/16.04/docker/1.12.1/standard/Dockerfile